# SwiftUI custom shape behavior not as expected

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I'm following Stanford CS193P 2020 youtube sessions. I got stuck with the behavior of my custom diamond shape. My custom shape frame (no matter which modifier I place frame, etc) is always bigger than the space where it is drawn and the built in shapes always take the given space. The result of this is that all my custom shapes have different sizes according to the space its frame takes. I don't know how to solve this problem.
The concrete question would be, how do I obtain the same frame in my custom shape as I obtain in rectangle or capsule?.
 I'll paste you an image of the drawing and the code below. Thanks for your help.

Custom shape code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Diamond:Shape {

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {

        var path = Path()
        // get the center of the rect
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        // get the smallest between height and width
        let minDimension = min(rect.width, rect.height)
        // get the starting of our drawing the right side of our diamond
        let startingPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x + minDimension / 2, y: center.y)
        // move our start of drawing to the beggining point
        path.move(to: startingPoint)
        // distance / 2 is our height
        // create all our points
        let secondPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x, y: center.y + minDimension / 4)
        let thirdPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x - minDimension / 2 , y: center.y)
        let fourthPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x, y: center.y - minDimension / 4)
        path.addLine(to: secondPoint)
        path.addLine(to: thirdPoint)
        path.addLine(to: fourthPoint)
        path.addLine(to: startingPoint)        
        return path
    }
}
```

Shapes drawing

```
import SwiftUI

struct SetCardView:View {

    var card:SetGame<Figure,Shade,FigureColor>.Card

    var body: some View {

        switch card.figureType {

        case .capsule:
            return AnyView(GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<self.card.numberOfFiguresInCard) { _ in
                        Capsule(style: .circular)
                            .stroke(self.card.figureColor.createColor(), lineWidth: 4)
                            .frame(maxWidth: min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height), maxHeight: min(geometry.size.width,geometry.size.height) / 2 )
                            .overlay(
                                Capsule(style: .circular)
                                    .fill(self.card.shadingType.createOpacity() != nil ? self.card.figureColor.createColor() : Color.white)
                                    .opacity(self.card.shadingType.createOpacity() ?? 1))
                            .frame(idealWidth: geometry.size.width, idealHeight: geometry.size.width / 3 )
                    }
                    .frame(idealWidth: geometry.size.width)
                    .padding()
                }.padding()
            })

        case .diamond:
            return AnyView(GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<self.card.numberOfFiguresInCard) { _ in
                        VStack {
                            Diamond()
                                .stroke(self.card.figureColor.createColor(), lineWidth: 4)
                                .overlay(
                                    Diamond()
                                        .fill(self.card.shadingType.createOpacity() != nil ? self.card.figureColor.createColor() : Color.white)
                                        .opacity(self.card.shadingType.createOpacity() ?? 1))
                        }
                    }.padding(.horizontal)
                }
            })

        case .squiggle:
            return AnyView(GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<self.card.numberOfFiguresInCard) { _ in
                        Rectangle()
                            .stroke(self.card.figureColor.createColor(), lineWidth: 4)
                            .frame(maxWidth: min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height), maxHeight: min(geometry.size.width,geometry.size.height) / 2 )
                            .overlay(
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(self.card.shadingType.createOpacity() != nil ? self.card.figureColor.createColor() : Color.white)
                                    .opacity(self.card.shadingType.createOpacity() ?? 1))
                            .frame(idealWidth: geometry.size.width)
                    }.padding()
                }.padding()
            })
        }
    }
}


struct SetCardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        let vm = FiguresSetGame()
        return SetCardView(card:vm.cards.filter{$0.numberOfFiguresInCard == 2 && $0.figureType == .diamond}[1])
    }
}
```

[image: Capsule shape's frame is the one that I want]
[image: Custom image]
[image: Blue rectangle shows the frame]

PD: I know I can improve my code a lot by removing it out of the function and making it not to repeat.

Comment: And what was expected? Because it draws as coded.

Comment: I expected the diamonds all to be of the same size no matter if they where 3, 2 or 1. And the same size as the capsule and rectangle. I also want the frames of the custom diamond to be the frames of the capsule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved I was drawing wrongly my diamond shape.
I needed to draw in the whole frame not, just the minimun dimension. Then the diamond would occupy the whole frame.

```
struct Diamond:Shape {

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {

        var path = Path()
        // get the center of the rect
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        // get the starting of our drawing the right side of our diamond
        let startingPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: center.y)
        // move our start of drawing to the beggining point
        path.move(to: startingPoint)
        // distance / 2 is our height
        // create all our points
        let secondPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x, y: rect.maxY)
        let thirdPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.minX , y: center.y)
        let fourthPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x, y: rect.minY)
        path.addLine(to: secondPoint)
        path.addLine(to: thirdPoint)
        path.addLine(to: fourthPoint)
        path.addLine(to: startingPoint)        
        return path
    }
}
```